# How to save multi people picker values using angularjs?

Tags: sharepoint, office365-restapi

How to save the multipeople picker values in sharepoint list using angularjs and rest api?

Answer (score 1):

visit http://matthewyarlett.blogspot.in/2015/04/using-microsoft-client-side-people.html
and costruct your metadata in this way
var taskProperties = {
    '__metadata' : { 'type': 'SP.Data.TasksListItem' },
    'Title': 'Order approval',
    **'AssignedToId' : { 'results': [10] }**
};

Answer (score 1):

For inserting multiple values to person or group column, we have to specify the ids of people or group.

```js
var taskProperties = {
    __metadata: { "type": "SP.Data.TasksListItem" },
    Title: "Order approval",
    AssignedToId: { 'results': [11,22] } 
}
```

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990131/CRUD-Operation-to-List-Using-SharePoint-Rest-API